# Pronunciation of the exclamation 'whew'

Tags: pronunciation

I know that [*phew*](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/phew) and [*whew*](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/whew) are both exclamations. However, I was surprised that although *phew* is pronounced as  /fjuː/, *whew* is pronounced as both /hwjuː/ and /fjuː/. How can *wh* be pronounced like *f*? Is there any other word where this happens? Is there any explanation for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that the oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com link you've posted has "whew" pronounced as "/fju:/". I think that [this link](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whew) is much more representative of how "whew" is intended to be read/heard.

As a native speaker, I have never seen or heard of "whew" being pronounced any way other than "/hwü/". I would always write "phew" (and never "whew") when I wanted to indicate the "eff" noise at the beginning of the word.